# Segmentation fault when storing lambda as std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

The following code gives me segmentation fault. After debugging it, I find out that the problem can be solved by declaring the lambda as auto rather than Function. Why is that the case?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> Vec;
typedef std::function<const Vec&(Vec)> Function;


int main()
{
     //Function func = [](const Vec& a)->Vec /*this give me segfault*/
     auto func = [](const Vec& a)->Vec /*this work just fine??*/
         {
              Vec b(2);
              b[0] = a[0] + a[1];
              b[1] = a[0] - a[0];
              return b;
         };
     Vec b = func(Vec{1,2});
     std::cout << b[0] << " " << b[1] << "\n";
     return 0;
}
```

It would be great if I can declare it as Function because I would like
to pass this lambda expression to some other classes.

The error that I have when func is declared as Function is:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000401896 in std::vector >::size (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:655 655         { return size_type(this->_M_impl._M_finish - this->_M_impl._M_start);
>   }
>   (gdb) backtrace
>   #0  0x0000000000401896 in std::vector >::size (this=0x0) at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:655
>   #1  0x00000000004015aa in std::vector >::vector (this=0x7fffffffdc50, __x=)
>       at /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:320
>   #2  0x0000000000400d12 in main () at test.cxx:18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be careful with function types, and it should work fine if you use the correct one;

```
typedef std::function<Vec(const Vec&)> Function;
```

Perhaps the issue gets clearer with fewer object wrappers and more conventional functions.

What it boils down to, once you remove the indirection through objects, is this:

```
// const Vec& -> Vec
std::vector<double> the_lambda(const std::vector<double>& x)
{
    return x;
}

// Vec -> const Vec&
const std::vector<double>& the_function(std::vector<double> x)
{
    return the_lambda(x);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = {1, 2};
    std::vector<double> lv = the_lambda(v);    // OK.
    std::vector<double> fv = the_function(v);  // Undefined.
}
```

This compiles, but g++ warns that `the_function` returns a reference to a temporary, which is exactly what happens with the `std::function` (but without so much as a hint from the compiler).

(I'm fairly convinced that allowing this conversion of the returned value in `std::function` is a mistake. You wouldn't get away with it if you were using function pointers, and C++ is supposed to be *more* safe than C, not less.)

Answer (score 6):

`const Vec&(Vec)` is equivalent to a lambda that looks like this `(Vec) -> const Vec&`. You pass a `(const Vec&) -> Vec`.

`std::function` accepts it due to the call sequence containing a valid conversion (You can pass a value to a function expecting a const reference).

The segmentation fault is most likely to the undefined behavior inherent in the return value of your lambda (a temporary) being bound to a const reference in `std::function`'s `operator()`; that reference is being returned outside of the `std::function` which immediately makes it a dangling reference.